# Get the Region of Interest(ROI) of an Image of a type Pix in Leptonica

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, roi, leptonica

I want to know what function shall I use to get the Region of Interest of an image of type Pix using [Leptonica Image Processing](http://tpgit.github.io/UnOfficialLeptDocs/leptonica/functions.html) Library. I already done this in OpenCV and I wanted a version of it in Leptonica. Thanks in Advance.

OpenCV Code:

```
Mat processedImage;
imwrite( "processedImage.tif", processedImage);
Rect region_of_interest = Rect(9, 10,11,20);
Mat tmp = processedImage(region_of_interest);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question with answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605513/crop-pictures-with-leptonica-api-or-which-image-processing-lib-to-use). You need to define a box to crop the region:

```
BOX* region = boxCreate(x, y, w, h);
PIX* imgCrop = pixClipRectangle(img, region, NULL);
```